# How to test page speed of staging sites?

Tags: automated-testing

Is there a way to you Google PageSpeed to test staging sites?

Currently it is not possible to test staging sites with the Google Tool.

Comment: I wrote up a whole explanation of how to automate this and then realize you may be asking a different question, so I put it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988762/how-to-do-automated-google-page-speed-insights-tests. What do you mean by staging sites? Is you problem you need to login or authenticate in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Staging sites work fine if they are accessible from the outside. So the solution is to open the firewall just for the Google PageSpeed tool (its IP address)

Comment: Hello timfredo thanks for your answer, do you have any link that details this?

Comment: Is there any other way if it is not possible to open the firewall?

Comment: I am not aware of any other methods for using PageSpeed behind the firewall, as it always runs on Google's servers. You can use Selenium, Kantu Browser or many other web testing tools for basic transaction runtime measurements, but I know, that is not the same.

Comment: i use staging.my_company_name.com and it's publically accessible and works fine for testing.  For page speed testing I often set up a different server but same applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can check speed of page through this link:https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: Thanks Rutvi for your answer, 
I want to test staging sites speed, which I can't with PageSpeed Insights

Answer (score 0):

You can check the staging sites using BrowserMobProxy https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy and there is also a free utility to help web developers to watch and manipulate network traffic from their AJAX applications. http://bmp.lightbody.net.

With browsermob proxy You can generate the Har file and use that har file to get the details of your websites performance. We have used this tool in our automated testing services to test the performance of websites in different environments.